# FactoryGirl objects not being dropped after tests. Please review my test setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Objects are persisting after tests run.  I confirmed by doing a `PowerUp.all.count` test and the count increases by 2 on each run, which a number equal to the objects created for the test on each run.  I don't know if I'm misusing FactoryGirl, or if I have a misconfigured spec_helper.

spec/support/factory_girl.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl'

RSpec.configure do |config|
config.order = :random

config.before(:all) do
  FactoryGirl.reload
end

  Kernel.srand config.seed

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.syntax = :expect
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.syntax = :expect
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

spec/api/power_up_spec.rb:

```
describe Api::PowerUpsController, :type => :controller do 

    describe "GET power_ups" do
        it "returns all power-ups" do 
            FactoryGirl.create :power_up, name: "Increase rate of take", description: "You gain points more quickly"
            FactoryGirl.create :power_up, name: "Decrease rate of give", description: "You lose points more slowly"

            get :index, :format => :json

            expect(response.status).to eq 200

            body = JSON.parse(response.body)
            power_up_names = body.map { |m| m["name"] }

            expect(power_up_names).to match_array(["Increase rate of take",
                                               "Decrease rate of give"])
        end

    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

This turns off the default behavior, which is to rollback transactions after each example. When set to `false` RSpec does not attempt to manage the test database.

You can use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to remove the rows created by tests when RSpec is not using transactions. This is often used when writing feature specs.

Comment: I'm glad you pointed that out.  Unfortunately, the problem persists. Any other ideas?

Comment: Meaning you set the value to `true` but it still fails to drop rows between tests?

Comment: Hmm. You could look in `log/test.log` to see if that tells you anything. Or just install DatabaseCleaner -- if you are using Capybara it is generally a better approach anyway.

Comment: Yea, DatabaseCleaner fixed me right up.  Thanks for the assist.